# How to fix program closing right after input statement

Tags: python

I'm making a simple text game in Python 3, and I tried to make an input statement, but when I answer it, the program closes. How can I fix this?

I've tried Googling it, but I just see "program closes straight after opening it".

```
def startgame():
    print("####################")
    ign = input("Type a name. ")
    print("####################")
    namedecision = input("You have picked " + ign + ".\nAre you sure you want\nto keep this name? (Y/N) ")
    if namedecision == ['y','Y']:
        # put game func
        print("####################")
    if namedecision == ['n', 'N']:
        ign = input("Type a name. ")
        namedecision = input("You have picked " + ign + ".")
        print("####################")
        # game func

startgame()
```

I expect that if I typed Y or N it would execute the proper functions.

Comment: is your program really indented like this? If so, you need to correct that.

Comment: Are you running it from the shell?

Comment: No, it's actually indented properly.

Do you mean the interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statements are always returning false because your input will always be a string, and you are comparing it to a list. Change your `==` for `in` in order to check if a string (or any other type) is in a list.

Corrected code:

```py
def startgame():
    print("####################")
    ign = input("Type a name. ")
    print("####################")
    namedecision = input("You have picked " + ign + ".\nAre you sure you want\nto keep this name? (Y/N) ")
    if nameDecision in ['y','Y']:
        # put game func
        print("####################")
    elif nameDecision in ['n', 'N']:
        ign = input("Type a name. ")
        namedecision = input("You have picked " + ign + ".")
        print("####################")

startgame()
```

Comment: [You have to wait 15 minutes to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer). Glad I could help!